# Create LIst/Library for SharePoint Online via a Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, document-library, designer-workflow

I know there are no out the box actions that allow you to create a new library from SharePoint Designer but there are plenty of 3rd party tools that offer it.

Is there any way to create a library using a POST call in Sharepoint Designer? Struggling to find any documentation or syntax that could provide the answer. The other option is to build a custom workflow via Visual Studio but if it can be achieved via a REST call then all the better.

As always, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "Call HTTP Web Service" action to do that.

There is a blog about creating a list using SharePoint Designer workflow, you can refer to it:
[How To Create A List Using HTTP Web Service In SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-a-list-using-http-web-service-in-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow/)

Comment: Set this REST call up this morning and it does the job. A quick change to one of the dictionaries and it was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

A more future proof alternativ could be to use a Flow, like this perhaps :https://medium.com/plumsail/how-to-call-sharepoint-from-microsoft-flow-with-a-help-of-an-azure-function-a5740794341

Comment: Will give the custom flow a go later today. Most likely won't be ideal but still a good solution.